# Mostrar contenido en la categoria correcta

Tags: php, html, wordpress

estoy realizando una web con ACF, y estoy teniendo complicaciones en como crear un bucle para que una parte del contenido se me cargue solo en la pagina de categorias con el slug: "tarifas-todas".

Para hacerlo lo que he hecho ha sido crear un Custom field( un slider) y le he dicho que me lo cargue solo en esa sección (que en la imagen aparece como tienda):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego le he dicho en el loop-archive.php que me lo cargue:

```html
<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>
  <h1><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'limon' ); ?></h1>
  <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found. Perhaps searching will help.', 'limon' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
    


                <div id="slide_home" class="full marginBottom_2em marginTop_1em">
                    <?php include('slide_nuevo.php')?>
                </div>

    
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="marginBottom_1em marginTop_1em">
            
         <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
             <header>
     <?php $url=get_permalink();?>
             </header>
           

   
                 
     <div class="marginTop_1em">
                     
                        <?php 
      $id = $post->ID;
      $categorias = get_the_terms($id, 'tipos-de-tarifas');
      $count = 0; 
      foreach($categorias as $categoria){
      $count ++;
      if($count == 1){
      $name = $categoria->slug;
      $id = $categoria->term_id;
      $name_id = 'tipos-de-tarifas_'.$id;
      $prueba = get_field('color', $name_id);
       }
      }
      ;?>
                        

         
                        
                        
                        
                       
                        <div class="grid_3 white paddingBottom_1em">
                         <a style="width:280px;min-height:200px!important;max-height:200px!important;" class="link" href="<?php echo $url;?>" ><br /></a>
                         <h3 class="white padding_1em"><?php the_field('velocidad'); ?></h3>
                         <div class="precio whitecolor padding_1em" style="background:<?php echo $prueba;?>;">
                          <p class="digitos"><?php the_field('precio'); ?></p>
                    <p class="decimales">,<?php the_field('decimales_precio'); ?></p>
                    <p class="euros">€/mes</p>
                    <p class="condiciones"><?php the_field('condiciones'); ?></p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="grid_9">
                         <h2 class="title left paddingTop_05em">
        <a title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'limon' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
       </h2>
                            <div class="right">
                            <?php 
      $id = $post->ID;
      $categorias = get_the_terms($id, 'tipos-de-tarifas');
      $count =  0;
      foreach($categorias as $categoria){
       $count++;
       //var_dump($categoria);
      $id = $categoria->term_id;
      $parent = $categoria->parent;
      if($count > 1){
       break;
      }
      //$ids = array_fill(0, 6, $id);
      //var_dump($ids);
       if($id == 15){
        }elseif($parent == 15){ }else{echo __('<a class="coberturas_button" href="#">Ver cobertura</a>', 'limon');}
      }
      ?>
                            
                            <a id="contratar_button" class="inline cboxElement" href="#formulario"><?php echo __('Alta online', 'limon');?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <ul class="caracteristicas">
                            
                            <?php $caracteristicas = get_field('caracteristicas');
         $velocidad = get_field('velocidad_de_bajada_y_subida');
        
         $count = 0;
         if (!empty($caracteristicas)){
          foreach( $caracteristicas as $caracteristica){
           $count ++;
           $caracteristica = $caracteristica['caracteristica'];
           $par = $count%2;
           if($par != 0){
             echo '<li class="grid_5 alpha omega izq"><p class="padding_1em">'.$caracteristica.'. </p></li>';
           }else{
            echo '<li class="grid_4 right alpha omega der"><p class="padding_1em">'.$caracteristica.'. </p></li>';
           }
             
          } 
          
          
            
          
           
          
          
          
       }?>
                             <div class="clear"></div>
                            </ul>
                            <?php if($velocidad){ 
        echo '<ul class="caracteristicas"><li class=""><p class="padding_1em"><strong>Velocidad de bajada/subida: '.$velocidad.'</strong></p></li></ul>';
        }?>
                            
                        </div><!--grid_9-->
                        
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        
     </div><!--marginTop_1em-->
     
      
   
             <footer>
             </footer>
         </article>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div><!--marginBottom_1em-->
<?php endwhile; // End the loop. Whew. ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>  
  <!-- <nav class="grid_8 textAlignRight"> Ocultar paginacion
         <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
  </nav> -->
 

<div class="clear"></div>  
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
</div>
```

Pero me lo carga en todas las categorías, y yo solo lo quiero que me lo cargue en una.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Las "location rules" de ACF solo aplican al backend, no podrás declarar condicionales de como se muestran los resultados en el frontend con esas "location rules". Ahora mismo tus "location rules" dicen que el control de esos custom fields se pueda realizar solo desde la página "tarifas internet", pero desde el admin.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que dices @Capiedge  ..Me estás diciendo que no se pueden aplicar location rules a esa pagina de loop-archive.php,... pero como hago entonces para mostrar algo solo en una categoria? tiene que haber alguno modo más sencillo ¿no?

Comment: Quizá cargando la página donde se cargan las categorias que es loop-archive con algun:<?php get_template_part('loop', 'page');?> y una vez que ya tenga eso cargado en una pagina nueva comenzar a maquetar?

Comment: Lo que te quiero decir es que las "location rules" controlan solo donde se mostrarán esos custom fields en el backend, para el frontend, tienes que hacer algun condicional del tipo: if( has_term( 'tarifas-internet', 'tipos-de-tarifas' ) )

Comment: ahhh ya se lo que quieres decir @Capiedge , y eso es lo que he preguntado en este post, cómo hago ese condicional para que solo me aparezca en la categoría que deseo, me has ayudado mucho, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguirlo, deberás usar un condicional que permita mostrar o no mostrar el código que muestra el slide.

Tomando como referencia los nombres de tu ejemplo concreto este sería:

```
if (has_term ('tarifas-internet', 'tipos-de-tarifas')) {
    //tu código
}
```

Ten en cuenta que este condicional, escrito así, solo funcionará dentro del loop.

Espero te haya servido de ayuda.
Saludos!

Comment: Sí, es esto lo que buscaba, por cierto una cosa más, sabes porqué si pongo en el Custom Field-->Post Taxonomy equal to Tienda.. me lo aplica a toda la categoria padre y no solo al hijo que le estoy diciendo? (lo que muestro en la foto de arriba)

Comment: Tal y como has definido las condiciones, el control de ese custom field, aparecerá en la página con nombre "tarifas internet" y que además (AND) tenga el valor (term) "tienda" marcado. Por cierto, si la respuesta es correcta, debes marcarla como tal ;)